# Postgresql: is there a psql version of the "@@" from Oracle sqlplus?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Does the Postgres client `psql` have a functionality like the `@@` of Oracle SQLPlus?

For those who are wondering what `@@` does: it allows to call a relative sql script from another script.

Comment: psql just has an ordinary include file mechanism, comparable to C's preprocessor. `\i other_script.sql` does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> `\ir` or `\include_relative` *filename*
>
> The `\ir` command is similar to `\i`, but resolves relative file names differently. When executing in interactive mode, the two commands behave identically. However, when invoked from a script, `\ir` interprets file names relative to the directory in which the script is located, rather than the current working directory.